# How to retrieve email using LinkedIn API after the v2 version deprecation?

Tags: linkedin-api

I have been using the LinkedIn API to retrieve the email addresses of members using the following endpoint:

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))`

However, I recently learned that as of the end of June 2023, the v2 version of the API has been deprecated. According to the documentation, I should now use the /rest/ endpoint. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any information on retrieving email addresses using the new endpoint in the documentation.

Can someone please guide me on how to retrieve email addresses using the LinkedIn API now that the v2 version has been deprecated? Specifically, I'm looking for the updated URL and any required parameters.